# Search bar in html using user input for url redirection

Tags: html, url, search, url-routing

I wish to have a search bar that goes to a specific URL. What I have now is the code pasted below, which goes to image_edit?path={path}. This is invoked by the tbox class I assume. What I want is for the path to be something along the lines of image_edit/path/index.html. Meaning the variable inputted by the user is used directly in the URL and not as a GET method variable for the variable 'path'. Thanks in advance for the help.

edit: better explanation:
The code below forms a form which goes to the url image_edit?path={path} where {path} is the user's input in the form. I want the url to be image_edit/{path}/index.html instead.

```
<form style="position: absolute; top: 115px; left: 1165px;" id="quick-search" method="get" action="image_edit">
  <fieldset class="search">
    <label for="path">Search:</label>
    <input class="tbox" id="input" type="text" name="path" value="" />
    <button class="btn">Search</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please, can you explain better your question?

Comment: Edited... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use some javascript to redirect to that location
first, remove the action

make a event handler onClick on the button to a js function and make it redirect to :

'image_edit/' +document.getElementbyId('input').value  '/index.html'